# Fetch data from .json file with fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I am trying to access data from an external json i created. The get request on that json works, i tested it with postman.
This is my code:

```
import "./Feedback.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Feedback() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/', {
            mode: 'no-cors'
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(
                        `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
                    );
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((actualData) => {
                setData(actualData.data);
                setError(null);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(err.message);
                setData([]);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="Feedback">
            <h1>Feedback List</h1>
            {loading && <div>A moment please...</div>}
            {error && (
                <div>{`There is a problem fetching the data - ${error}`}</div>
            )}
            <ul>
                {data &&
                    data.map(({data }) => (
                        <li key={data.author.id}>
                            <h3>{data.author.username}</h3>
                            <p>{data.author.email}</p>
                        </li>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My json looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
{
"author": {
"about_me": "Memory when air true.",
"avatar_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/45c4df639b815ffffb06d9d3df4466e1?d=identicon",
"email": "breed@example.net",
"first_seen": "2023-03-26T14:26:07.708305Z",
"id": 1,
"last_seen": "2023-03-26T16:20:22.923657Z",
"posts_url": "/api/users/1/posts",
"url": "/api/users/1",
"username": "kevinwashington"
},
"id": 90,
"text": "Figure the impact song think. Magazine throughout college site knowledge.",
"timestamp": "2023-03-23T18:07:23Z",
"url": "/api/posts/90"
},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items},
{5 items}
],
"pagination": {
"count": 25,
"limit": 25,
"offset": 0,
"total": 43
}
}
```

On my website it shows me:
"
Feedback List
There is a problem fetching the data - This is an HTTP error: The status is 0
"
What am i doing wrong, how can i show all authors in the data with all their data

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. Each value and key should be wrapped in double quotes. Also, why do you specify `no-cors`?

Comment: @JBrown i had to specify no-cors, since it wouldnt work otherwise with my browser. but i dont get why that wouldnt be valid JSON?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Are the `5 items` objects just an abbreviation? Either way, can you share the entire error object? Not just the status code?

Comment: @JBrown ah yeah that was my mistake not to mention. the {5 items}, are just other authors, i shortened them with JSON viewer pro for this question, so it doesnt take as much room in this question. tbh that is the entire error object. it shows that sentence because i clarified throw new Error(
                        `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
                    );
in my code

Comment: Just answered. Let me know if that works

Comment: @JBrown not yet, could it be that i am accessing the data from the json in the wrong way? how would you map them to show them all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252919/discussion-between-jbrown-and-eraser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the error message from the `response()` section. If you are using `then().catch()` anytime you enter the `then()` block, the response was successful. So you are actually creating an error when there was not one probably because `response.ok` does not exist. You need to remove `no-cors` too.

Also, you are not returning anything from the map function which will result in no data being displayed. Try updating your code to this:

```js
import "./Feedback.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Feedback() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((actualData) => {
                setData(actualData.data);
                setError(null);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(err.message);
                setData([]);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="Feedback">
            <h1>Feedback List</h1>
            {loading && <div>A moment please...</div>}
            {error && (
                <div>{`There is a problem fetching the data - ${error}`}</div>
            )}
            <ul>
                {data &&
                data.map((d) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={d.author.id}>
                      <h3>{d.author.username}</h3>
                      <p>{d.author.email}</p>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```